# Grep based on pattern

Tags: bash, unix, awk

Sample Text:

```
This is a test
This is aaaa test
This is aaa test
This is test a
This aa is test
```

---

I have just started learning unix commands like grep, awk and sed and have a quick question. If my text file contains the above text how can I just print out lines that use the letter ‘a’ 2 or fewer times.

I tried using awk, but don’t understand the syntax to add up all the instances of ‘a’ and only print the lines that have ‘a’ 2 or fewer times. I understand comparing numbers based on columns like awk ‘$1 <=2’ but don’t know how to use that with characters as well. Any help would be appreciated.

---

Essentially it should print out:

```
This is a test
This is test a
This aa is test
```

For Clarity: I don't want to remove the extra As, but rather only print the lines that contain two or fewer As.

Comment: 2 or fewer _consecutive_ 'a' instances or _anywhere_ on the line?

Comment: Why did you not say that when you posted your example, and why do you not updated it when some one ask for it and you confirm it. `-1` for this.

Answer (score 2):

like this?

```
kent$  grep  -v 'aaa\+' file      
This is a test
This is test a
This aa is test
```

### Update

I just saw the comment, if your requirement is **anywhere** on the line, no matter consecutive or not, see the example (with awk):

```
kent$  cat f
1a  a
2a
3
4a a a aa
5aaaaaaaaaa

kent$  awk 'gsub(/a/,"a")<3' f
1a  a
2a
3
```

#### without `gsub`:

```
kent$  awk -F'a' 'NF<4' f      
1a  a
2a
3
```

Comment: Oh sorry if I was unclear, I don't want to remove the extra As, but rather only print the lines that contain two or fewer As.

Comment: @user3211189 my bad, updated the answer with grep, only extract/print those lines from file.

Comment: @user3211189 edit for the comment (anywhere on the line)

Comment: @user3211189 see update. you we can check the `NF` too.

Comment: @user3211189 You asked things in comment, but removed after got answer. can you just keep your comments there? so that people know what was going on??

Comment: @user3211189 NF would be the count of `a` +1. E.g: 2 As, we have NF=3. -> `foo a bar a baz`

Comment: +1 for `awk -F'a' 'NF<4' f`, which is the most elegant solution; please feature it prominently, now that we're clear on the OP's requirements. Also, please represent the prompt as just `$` (and - [ceterum censeo](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceterum_censeo) - remember not to use `7` for `1` :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`

```
awk '!/aaa+/' file
This is a test
This is test a
This aa is test
```

Do not print lines with three or more `a` together.

---

Same with `sed`

```
sed '/aaa\+/d' file
This is a test
This is test a
This aa is test
```

Default for `sed` is to print all line. `/aaa\+/d` tells `sed` to delete lines with 3 or more `a`

Comment: +1 for elegant solutions for filtering out 3 or more _consecutive_ occurrences of `'a'` (we've since learned that the OP is looking for occurrences _anywhere_ on the line).